# Problema con api google cloud storage

Tags: php, google-api, google-cloud-storage

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
<?php

require('/vendor/autoload.php');
use Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageClient;

function getName($objName){
    return $objName->name();
}

function uploadFile($obju, $sourceu, $bucketName){
    $file = fopen($sourceu, 'r');
    $bucketu = $obju->bucket($bucketName);
    $objectu = $bucketu->upload($file, [
       'name' => $bucketName.'.html',
       'predefinedAcl' => 'publicRead'
    ]);
    fclose($file);
    setLink($bucketName);
}

function createBucket($objc,$rtc){
    $bucketc = $objc->createBucket($rtc);
    $name_bucket = getName($bucketc);
    uploadFile($objc, 'index.html',$name_bucket);
}

function initHandler($projectId, $serviceAccountPath, $rt){
    $config = [
        'keyFilePath' => $serviceAccountPath,
        'projectId' => $projectId
    ];
    $objStorage = new StorageClient($config);
    createBucket($objStorage, $rt);
}

function setLink($fb){
    return json_encode(array(
        'shortUrl' => 'https://'.$fb.'.storage.googleapis.com/'.$fb.'.html'
    ));
}

//header('Content-Type: application/json');
$rand = mt_rand();
$rt = $rand;
initHandler('loloxd8094192506', '/client.json', $rt);

?>
```

al ejecutarlo en un servidor online me sale esto:

> Esta página no funciona La página "dominio.com" no puede procesar esta solicitud ahora.
>
> HTTP ERROR 500

Notas: tengo la carpeta vendor de composer con la dependencia de google-cloud-storage, y los respectivos archivos de composer, .json, .lock etc.